# Foundation 4 Top-Bar Conditional data-options

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

The only way to get the Foundation 4 top-bar working in IE10 is to bypass hover events and change them to onClick, using data options, in this case:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-options="is_hover:false">
```

Now, this is the only workaround I can think of for IE10, even though it's not ideal; people still expect to be able to hover on a menu and get a drop down.

Trouble is, I don't really want this behaviour on every browser! Can anybody think of a way to conditionally serve up behaviours for the other browsers?

Comment: Did you found a way to solve it?